# Is it possible to unit test a Raspberry Pi (ARM) device using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I've got a Universal Windows app that runs on my Pi using the ARM processor architecture. I've added a Universal Windows unit test project to the solution with a reference to the main app. I'd like to be able to run unit tests against the real hardware but I'm not sure if this is possible since there is no ARM processor selection available under Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture. When I attempt to run a unit test with "Remote Machine" selected I get this error:

`------ Run test started ------
Failed to connect to remote device with id 'pi3'. Error returned: '-1989083101'.
Unit tests in source C:\garagedoor\GarageDoorUnitTest\bin\ARM\Debug\GarageDoorUnitTest.exe cannot be run. Please create a Windows Store or Windows Phone Unit Test project.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:20.2450056) ==========`

Comment: By definition, unit tests should be irrelevant to the real hardware. You should mock up all the dependent objects.

Comment: If you're doing TDD I would think you'd want to see your app running on the real hardware. The other problem is that I can't run a Pi3 simulator using Visual Studio on my machine (Hyper-V is not supported in Win 10 Home). Thanks again, M$.

Comment: Except that we don't see tests running on real hardware as "unit test". Currently UWP unit test project runs only on x86 and x64. There's no way to make it work on ARM.